# Write with ObjectOutputStream into multiple ZipEntrys in a single ZipOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization, io

I want to create a zip archive in Java where each contained file is produced by serializing some objects. I have a problem with correctly closing the streams.

The code looks like this:

```
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
     ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(os);) {

  ZipEntry ze;
  ObjectOutputStream oos;

  ze = new ZipEntry("file1");
  zos.putNextEntry(ze); // start first file in zip archive
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(zos);
  oos.writeObject(obj1a);
  oos.writeObject(obj1b);
  // I want to close oos here without closing zos
  zos.closeEntry(); // end first file in zip archive

  ze = new ZipEntry("file2");
  zos.putNextEntry(ze); // start second file in zip archive
  oos = new ObjectOutputStream(zos);
  oos.writeObject(obj2a);
  oos.writeObject(obj2b);
  // And here again
  zos.closeEntry(); // end second file in zip archive
}
```

I know of course that I should close each stream after finishing using it, so I should close the `ObjectOutputStream`s in the indicated positions. However, closing the `ObjectOutputStream`s would also close the `ZipOutputStream` that I still need.

I do not want to omit the call to `ObjectOutputStream.close()` because I do not want to rely on the fact that it currently does not more than `flush()` and `reset()`.

I also cannot use a single `ObjectOutputStream` instance because then I miss the stream header that is written by the constructor (each single file in the zip archive would not be a full object serialization file, and I could not de-serialize them independently).

The same problem occurs when reading the file again.

The only way I see would be to wrap the `ZipOutputStream` in some kind of "CloseProtectionOutputStream" that would forward all methods except `close()` before giving it to the `ObjectOutputStream`. However, this seems rather hacky and I wonder if I missed a nicer solution in the API.

Comment: IMHO the problem lies in the ZIP API rather than in OOS. Instead of funny things like `closeEntry` it should give you a proper output stream, which you could `close` (see TrueZip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `OutputStream` wrapper throws an exception when closed more than once, it is not a hack. You can create a wrapper for each zip entry.

From an architectural point of view, I think the `ObjectOutputStream` author should have provided an option to disable `close()` cascading. You are just workarounding his lacking API.

Answer (score 3):

If you're intending to throw the ObjectOutputStream away anyway, then it should be sufficient to call `flush()` rather than `close()`, but as you say in the question the safest approach is probably to use a wrapper around the underlying ZipOutputStream that blocks the `close()` call.  Apache commons-io has [CloseShieldOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CloseShieldOutputStream.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, and for all the reasons you mentioned, I would simply not pipe my `ObjectOutputStream` to the `ZipOutputStream`. Instead, serialize to a `byte[]` and then write that straight into the `ZipOutputStream`. This way, you are free to close the `ObjectOutputStream` and each `byte[]` you produce will have the proper header from the serializer. One down side is you wind up with a `byte[]` in memory that you didn't have before but if you get rid of it right away, assuming we're not talking about millions of objects, the garbage collector shouldn't have a hard time cleaning up.

Just my two cents...

It at least sounds less hacky than a stream subclass that changes the `close()` behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, in general it seems like a suitable solution. In my use case, I have hundreds of megabytes or even gigabytes of data, so this is not feasible unfortunately.